# Can you restrict direction of drag in HTML5 drag and drop API (not jQuery-UI)?

Tags: html, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to restrict the drag of an element to only horizontal or vertical direction. I am using HTML5 drag and drop API and not Jquery UI. Here is simplified code I am using to move an element:

```
  $("#movedElem").on("dragstart", (event) => {
   event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed= "move";
   return true;
  });

  $("#targetElem").on("dragenter", (event) => {
  //...
  });

  $("#targetElem").on("dragover", (event) => {
     //
     event.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#targetElem").on("drop", (event) => {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     $('#targetElem').append($('#movedElem'));
  });
```

I am not looking for code, though that would be good too, but some direction would be enough... I think this must be a common requirement but could not find any example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967944/html5-draggable-within-a-boundary

Comment: @sonic Thanks but that was a long time ago.  Has anything changed or is there another API or small plugin workaround. I would hate to use jQuery UI just for this. jQuery base would be fine. If jQuery can do it, sure the support exists in plain Javascript to do this?

Comment: I don't know I was just curious about the problem you have. It's absurd that you can't do that simple thing but... The API itself is designed for other puproses, even if the post is old it contains the answer.

Comment: I found interact.js and there you have something like restrict. https://interactjs.io/docs/restriction/

Comment: [This](https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop) article explains how to do it yourself.